# What is the meaning? "AUTH USER morris result 504"

Tags: linux

Spam block Server

what is the meaning
| " AUTH USER morris result 504" |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that an attempted authentication for the user 'morris' ended in a result-code of 504. The exact meaning of that 504 code depends on your software.

Comment: +1 504 typically means that the command requires authentication; in this case it might mean that TLS/SSL is required to use that form of authentication. As Sysadmin said, it depends on your software.